# Is there a command-line switch to specify a relay for Sendmail

Tags: unix, sendmail, solaris

Similar to the "mailx" flag "-S relay.corp.com".

Read a Sun man file, haven't found anything.

OS is Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such switch for "sendmail by sendmail.org".
Some "sendmail look alike" allow something like that e.g. [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/).

Quick inet search suggests [msmtp is available as Solaris package](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWmsmtp/)